# Changing lists within a function

Tags: python

I am trying to load from a text file into a list, but it seems to be completely ignored. The relevant code:

```
pupils = []

def Load():    
    in_file = open("school.txt", "rb")
    pupils = pickle.load(open("school.txt", "rb"))
    in_file.close()

print(pupils)
```

I expect it to print the entire list but it returns a `NameError: 'pupils' is not defined`. Even if I just change it to `pupils = ["A", "B"]` it returns the same error. Why won't the list change?

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: declare `pupils` as global in your `Load` function:

```
def Load():
    global pupils
    ....
```

Better answer:  return the list from `Load` and assign it to `pupils`.

```
def Load():
    with open('school.txt','rb') as p_file:
        pupils = pickle.load(p_file)
    return pupils

pupils = Load()
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. But if `in_file` points to the file being opened, why is the second `open("school.txt", "rb")` necessary?

Comment: It's not :).  I just copied and pasted from your question.  I've edited it to eliminate the redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

return pupils from Load():

```
return pupils
```

and:

```
pupils = Load()
print(pupils)
```

One thing to realize, the variable pupils in function Load() is not the same as the one outside - they are two different variables, each with their own scope, just happened to share the same name, and nothing more than that.

You can also make pupils global, but that's never a good idea - as your script grows in size, global variable adds extra complicity and difficulty for maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

In python, if you want to reference global variables(eg. `pupils`), it requires you to be explicit. That means using the `global` keyword.

Because you didn't use `global`, When you tried to refer to `pupils` inside of your function, Python though you were referring to a list defined inside of the `Load()` function. When it didn't find what it was looking for, it raised a `NameError`. [Here the documentation on `global`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

> The `global` statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.

To fix your problem, you need to tell Python you want to use the global `puplis` list, and not a local list called `pupils`:

```
pupils = []

def Load():    
    global pupils # expictlly tell Python you referring to the global pupils list
    in_file = open("school.txt", "rb")
    pupils = pickle.load(open("school.txt", "rb"))
    in_file.close()

print(pupils)
```

However, it's almost never a good idea to use global variables. As your list grows in size, so does your global variable count. Having many global variable will lead to hard to read and confusing code.

Instead of making pupils global, make a *local* list called `pupils`, add the names to that list, and return the list. When you call the list, assign the return value to another, different variable named `pupils`. This method avoids having to keep any global state and is a more idiomatic method:

```
def Load():    
    in_file = open("school.txt", "rb")
    pupils = pickle.load(open("school.txt", "rb")) # local pupils list
    in_file.close()
    return pupils

pupils = Load()
```